# How to plot loss vs number of epochs for a linear regression model with using only sklearn and matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Now I want to plot a loss curve for number of epochs for both train and test data, how do I do that?

I tried many thing which included tensorflow, keras and all. But I ended up being confused.

Comment: Where in your code does the epochs occur? Do you mean iterations i.e the ones refered to  using `max_iter` in `LogisticRegression`?

Comment: I want it to plot till the number of epochs where the gradient descent finds the best value of parameters
(I am kind of new to machine learning, so ignore my stupidity if possible)

Comment: The epochs occur when I fit the model, it occurs in the backend and since I am using sklearn to fit the model and find the best suitable parameters, I am not able to see the number of epochs. That's what I think.